# Can I update a label in a UIButton without redrawing the button?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, delegates, nstimer

I want a clock readout to appear as a label in a `UIButton` once every second. But even though I remove it from the `superView` the new `UIButton` overwrites the old one, like this [image]
*… and after several minutes of this my iPhone looked seriously burnt :-)*

In `PlayViewController` my `NSTimer` methods look like this

```
    - (void)startClock {    
        clockCount         =  0;       // start on 1st clock pulse
        totalMinutes       =  0;        // appears on clockButton
        totalSeconds       =  0;        // appears on clockButton

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:STATES_ConcertClock
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(nextClock)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    }

    - (void)nextClock {

        self.lastEventChangeTime = [NSDate date];    
        clockCount++;
        [self masterClockReadout];    
    }
```

and here is my clock readout method

```
    - (void)masterClockReadout                              {
        totalMinutes       = clockCount / 60;
        totalSeconds       = clockCount % 60;
        clockString        = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", totalMinutes, totalSeconds];

        [self.seconds removeFromSuperview];
        EscButton *seconds = [[EscButton alloc] loadEscButton:(NSString *)clockString];
        [self.view addSubview:seconds];
    }
```

I also set a `UIView` property so `removeFromSuperview` knows what to remove.

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* seconds;
```

My question is: can I update the `UIButton` label without redrawing the button ? and, is this a problem that might be solved by using a `delegate` ?

To date my experience using `delegates` has been for sending messages from the `UIButton` to `ViewController`*(e.g. below)* but so far I haven't found an example I am able to apply where messages are sent in the opposite direction. So if using a `delegate` is the recommended approach, could you please point me to some code that might help me solve this problem. Thanks

**EscButton.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @protocol EscButtonDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)fromEscButton:(UIButton*)button;
    @end

    @interface EscButton : UIView {    
    }
    - (id)loadEscButton:(NSString *)text;
    @property (assign) id<EscButtonDelegate> delegate;
    @end
```

**EscButton.m**

```
    #import "EscButton.h"

    @implementation EscButton

    - (id)loadEscButton:(NSString *)text                          {

        CGFloat sideOffset   = screenWidth - ESC_BUTTON_Width - MARGIN_Side;
        CGFloat topOffset    = statusBarHeight + MARGIN_Top;

        UIButton *escButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        escButton.frame      = CGRectMake(sideOffset, topOffset, ESC_BUTTON_Width, ESC_BUTTON_Height);

      //      etc …

        [escButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(fromEscButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [escButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      //       etc …

        return escButton;
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to constantly add and remove a button. You can keep the same one. Change the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* seconds;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *secondsB;
```

Also change:

```
[self.seconds removeFromSuperview];
EscButton *seconds = [[EscButton alloc] loadEscButton:(NSString *)clockString];
[self.view addSubview:seconds];
```

to:

```
if (!self.secondsB) {

    self.secondsB = [[EscButton alloc] loadEscButton:(NSString *)clockString];
    [self.view addSubview:_secondsB]; // previously addSubview:seconds]; 
}

[self.secondsB setTitle:clockString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: do you mean  [self.view addSubview:secondsB]; ?

Comment: RunLoop, this solved my problem when I changed the line I commented. I'm going with your answer.